# How to get html input button to properly display resource.resx key / value entry?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a simplified demonstration of the issue.  will not display a string separated by white space.

```
@{
    var  myString = "worda wordb wordc";
}
<div class="row">
    <input value=@myString>
</div>
```

Using a C# resource file for multi language support, I'm having problems with web page input buttons. They will not display all data apart of resource file values. The same data will display properly using other html tags.

[image]

Create default mvc project > Add properties\resource.resx > add one entry to   file (make sure value has more than one word) > set file properties Custom Tool= PublicResXFileCodeGenerator > change index.cshtml to this code > set to chrome browser > run project. Notice the input tag will not display all data from resource file properly but other html tags will.

resources.resx

```
  <data name="updated_information_btn" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Word1 Word2 Word3</value>
  </data>
```

index.cshtml

```
@using TestBnResourceFile.Properties
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Testing button value displayed</h2>
    <p>
        Button has problem displaying all words of resource file key.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <h2>
        <span>"Resources.updated_information_btn" value:</span> @Resources.updated_information_btn
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" name="submitbtn1" value=@Resources.updated_information_btn class="submitbtn">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" name="submitbtn2" value=@Resources.updated_information_btn>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input name="submitbtn3" value=@Resources.updated_information_btn>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input value=@Resources.updated_information_btn>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to reference the string value in the following way:

```
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" name="date" value="<%= ResourceValue %>" />
</div>
```

So, if you want to bind the resource value, you can assign it to a string var and then set it:

```
private string ResourceValue{ get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.ResourceValue = @Resources.resource_value;
}
```

Let me know if it helps, cheers.

Comment: I tried this but ended up with <%=  ...  %> as apart of my string. Just the double quotes helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes around the variable resolved this issue.

```
@{
    var  myString = "worda wordb wordc";
}
<div class="row">
    <input value="@myString">
</div>
```